# Change in code behaviour after Laravel update 5.1.28 to 5.1.43

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have the following model.

```
class Property extends Model
{
    public function bedroom()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Bedroom');
     }

    public function week()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Week');
    }
}
```

I then sometimes eager load the week and sometimes do not.

I.e.

```
$property = Property::with('bedroom');
```

Later my code had the following line:

```
if (isset($property->week)) {
```

Now this worked fine before I ran composer update. As I hadn't eager loaded week, the IF statement would return false. If I did a DD dump, I could see that $property does not contain the relation Week.

Since running composer update, this line now works differently and eager loads the weeks, making the if statement always true. If I do a DD dump after the IF statement, it now shows the Week relation. By asking if the relation exists, it is loading the relation.

Composer Update updated the framework from 5.1.28 to 5.1.43

Comment: The behaviour I would expect would be for it to load the relationship. If anything, I'm not sure why it didn't do that before you updated. You can check if a relationship is loaded using `$modelInstance->relationLoaded('week')`

Comment: This should not have anything to do with Laravel. When accessing these dynamic properties though Eloquent, the magic method `__get()` is called. That's not called at all when using `isset` though, so updating the framework shouldn't change this behaviour.

Comment: Thanks Jonathon, using relationLoaded instead of isset gets me back to how the code used to work. Strange though that behaviour has changed, or rather strange that it didn't work that way prior to the update. Thanks for your help both of you.